# Inconsistency of `read_points` and opencv coordinates?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, depth-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to get lines from an image and get the corresponding points from a point cloud.

Note that I ran Realsense camera D455 and ran [a launch file](https://github.com/JinraeKim/myros/blob/main/point_cloud_xyzrgb.launch) that converts color and depth images to a point cloud, based on [[point_cloud_xyzrgb, depth_image_proc]](http://wiki.ros.org/depth_image_proc#depth_image_proc.2Fpoint_cloud_xyzrgb).

For now, I detected lines from a color image as described [here](https://github.com/JinraeKim/mlsd_pytorch/blob/stair-line-detectors/stair_line_detector_ros.py#L41-L46).
Note that I artifically chose only one line for the test (`lines = [lines[-1]]`).
Then, read the corresponding points from the ponit cloud like [this](https://github.com/JinraeKim/mlsd_pytorch/blob/stair-line-detectors/stair_line_detector_ros.py#L66-L75) using [point_cloud2.read_points](https://docs.ros.org/en/api/sensor_msgs/html/namespacesensor__msgs_1_1point__cloud2.html#a5d969a10974e5f12199d0da5a7f3ec92). Note that I can choose specific points by giving the argument `uvs`.

I thought `uvs` is an iterator of `(u, v)` where `u` and `v` corresponds to `uv` coordinate systems in opencv.
That is, `u` is right, `v` is down.

But the result looks like it is flipped.

Here are intermediate results:

- `lines[0]`

`array([411.38839626, 186.68757629, 442.08746529, 539.14202881])`

(each line = `[x1, y1, x2, y2]`)

- `line_iterators[0]`, that is, points along with each line on the color image:

(Pdb) p line_iterators[0]

```
[[411, 187], [411, 188], [411, 189], [411, 190], [411, 191], [411, 192], [411, 193], [411, 194], [411, 195], [411, 196], [411, 197], [412, 198], [412, 199], [412, 200], [412, 201], [412, 202], [412, 203], [412, 204], [412, 205], [412, 206], [412, 207], [412, 208], [413, 209], [413, 210], [413, 211], [413, 212], [413, 213], [413, 214], [413, 215], [413, 216], [413, 217], [413, 218], [413, 219], [413, 220], [414, 221], [414, 222], [414, 223], [414, 224], [414, 225], [414, 226], [414, 227], [414, 228], [414, 229], [414, 230], [414, 231], [415, 232], [415, 233], [415, 234], [415, 235], [415, 236], [415, 237], [415, 238], [415, 239], [415, 240], [415, 241], [415, 242], [416, 243], [416, 244], [416, 245], [416, 246], [416, 247], [416, 248], [416, 249], [416, 250], [416, 251], [416, 252], [416, 253], [416, 254], [417, 255], [417, 256], [417, 257], [417, 258], [417, 259], [417, 260], [417, 261], [417, 262], [417, 263], [417, 264], [417, 265], [418, 266], [418, 267], [418, 268], [418, 269], [418, 270], [418, 271], [418, 272], [418, 273], [418, 274], [418, 275], [418, 276], [418, 277], [419, 278], [419, 279], [419, 280], [419, 281], [419, 282], [419, 283], [419, 284], [419, 285], [419, 286], [419, 287], [419, 288], [420, 289], [420, 290], [420, 291], [420, 292], [420, 293], [420, 294], [420, 295], [420, 296], [420, 297], [420, 298], [420, 299], [421, 300], [421, 301], [421, 302], [421, 303], [421, 304], [421, 305], [421, 306], [421, 307], [421, 308], [421, 309], [421, 310], [421, 311], [422, 312], [422, 313], [422, 314], [422, 315], [422, 316], [422, 317], [422, 318], [422, 319], [422, 320], [422, 321], [422, 322], [423, 323], [423, 324], [423, 325], [423, 326], [423, 327], [423, 328], [423, 329], [423, 330], [423, 331], [423, 332], [423, 333], [423, 334], [424, 335], [424, 336], [424, 337], [424, 338], [424, 339], [424, 340], [424, 341], [424, 342], [424, 343], [424, 344], [424, 345], [425, 346], [425, 347], [425, 348], [425, 349], [425, 350], [425, 351], [425, 352], [425, 353], [425, 354], [425, 355], [425, 356], [426, 357], [426, 358], [426, 359], [426, 360], [426, 361], [426, 362], [426, 363], [426, 364], [426, 365], [426, 366], [426, 367], [426, 368], [427, 369], [427, 370], [427, 371], [427, 372], [427, 373], [427, 374], [427, 375], [427, 376], [427, 377], [427, 378], [427, 379], [428, 380], [428, 381], [428, 382], [428, 383], [428, 384], [428, 385], [428, 386], [428, 387], [428, 388], [428, 389], [428, 390], [429, 391], [429, 392], [429, 393], [429, 394], [429, 395], [429, 396], [429, 397], [429, 398], [429, 399], [429, 400], [429, 401], [429, 402], [430, 403], [430, 404], [430, 405], [430, 406], [430, 407], [430, 408], [430, 409], [430, 410], [430, 411], [430, 412], [430, 413], [431, 414], [431, 415], [431, 416], [431, 417], [431, 418], [431, 419], [431, 420], [431, 421], [431, 422], [431, 423], [431, 424], [431, 425], [432, 426], [432, 427], [432, 428], [432, 429], [432, 430], [432, 431], [432, 432], [432, 433], [432, 434], [432, 435], [432, 436], [433, 437], [433, 438], [433, 439], [433, 440], [433, 441], [433, 442], [433, 443], [433, 444], [433, 445], [433, 446], [433, 447], [434, 448], [434, 449], [434, 450], [434, 451], [434, 452], [434, 453], [434, 454], [434, 455], [434, 456], [434, 457], [434, 458], [434, 459], [435, 460], [435, 461], [435, 462], [435, 463], [435, 464], [435, 465], [435, 466], [435, 467], [435, 468], [435, 469], [435, 470], [436, 471], [436, 472], [436, 473], [436, 474], [436, 475], [436, 476], [436, 477], [436, 478], [436, 479], [436, 480], [436, 481], [436, 482], [437, 483], [437, 484], [437, 485], [437, 486], [437, 487], [437, 488], [437, 489], [437, 490], [437, 491], [437, 492], [437, 493], [438, 494], [438, 495], [438, 496], [438, 497], [438, 498], [438, 499], [438, 500], [438, 501], [438, 502], [438, 503], [438, 504], [439, 505], [439, 506], [439, 507], [439, 508], [439, 509], [439, 510], [439, 511], [439, 512], [439, 513], [439, 514], [439, 515], [439, 516], [440, 517], [440, 518], [440, 519], [440, 520], [440, 521], [440, 522], [440, 523], [440, 524], [440, 525], [440, 526], [440, 527], [441, 528], [441, 529], [441, 530], [441, 531], [441, 532], [441, 533], [441, 534], [441, 535], [441, 536], [441, 537], [441, 538], [442, 539]]
```

Therefore, the line_iterator looks fine. Also, I can draw a line on the image to check it whether it's correct or not.
The blue line in [this photo](https://github.com/JinraeKim/mlsd_pytorch/blob/stair-line-detectors/lines.png) corresponds to the `lines[0]` that I printed.

[This](https://github.com/JinraeKim/mlsd_pytorch/blob/stair-line-detectors/entire_points.png) is the visualisation of the entire point cloud. And in [this photo,](https://github.com/JinraeKim/mlsd_pytorch/blob/stair-line-detectors/summary.png) the white line in the point cloud corresponds to the line.

As you can see, it looks like the y-coordinate is flipped.

So my question is:

1. What coordinate does `uvs` follow in `read_points`?
2. Is there any something that I did wrongly?

EDIT: sorry for the poor visualisation. I edited the links for better visualisation.

EDIT2: I'm so sorry. I guess the problem is that lines are defined for the specific aspect ratio (512 x 512), which is different from streaming images. After fixing this if it works, I'll take a note here.

EDIT3: It was my fault. I fixed my mistake (the aspect ratio issue) and checked that it works well according to @Mike's answer!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/405581/inconsistency-of-%60read_points%60-and-opencv-coordinates?/) by [iHany](https://answers.ros.org/users/92871/ihany/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2022-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What coordinate does uvs follow in read_points?

The `uvs` argument is a list of (x,y) coordinates. "Iterable" is referring to the fact that uvs is a list. The coordinate system is that of the full PointCloud2. For the 2-D arrangement of Points, the message definition does not specify whether the rows are ordered top-to-bottom or bottom-to-top. In my experience, the origin is in upper left, with y incrementing as you move down the rows.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1